# Install minimal MonoDevelop, only for C#?

Tags: programming, mono, monodevelop

I'd like to install MonoDevelop with only the tools and libraries for creating console/GTK apps, but I'm unsure how to only select certain packages I need.
How could I do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install monodevelop mono-mcs
```